# FATAL:credentials.cc(127)

Tags: google-chrome, brave

I've installed chrome along ago, and recently doesn't start up, also installed brave browser and it's the same. been looking, and update the "keys" for chrome but it keeps failing, when i try to start it from terminal it goes:

> fritz@fritz-N56VJ:~$ google-chrome
> [50426:50426:0606/110538.495154:FATAL:credentials.cc(127)] Check failed: . : Permission denied (13)
> Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

The same for brave browser:

> ritz@fritz-N56VJ:~$ brave-browser
> [50447:50447:0606/110547.504124:FATAL:credentials.cc(127)] Check failed: . : Permission denied (13)
> /usr/bin/brave-browser: line 48: 50447 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) "$HERE/brave" "$@"

Thanks for taking your time to help.

cheers.

Comment: chrome, brave uses chromium. same goes for vscode. Reboot, pick another kernel (1 up or 1 down your current) and see if that solves it. Also: got an nvidia gpu? if so remove or install the 3rd party driver to see if that is the cause. Also have a look at the "core" log that got dumped.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'll give a try, thanks a lot.

Comment: Same here when updating kernel from 5.15 to 5.19. The grub options to boot 5.15 doesn't work for some reason (I get an infinite black screen). The nvidia-lowlatency option keeps giving this error.

Comment: So, should we wait for a bug fix or should we change the operating system?

Answer (score 0):

So I  came across this problem and I struggle a lot to find out a solution. One easy step I did to solve this problem is to switch to another kernel version.

To do this you can do:

1. [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) already said in the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471028/fatalcredentials-cc127?newreg=e39dda26495b42ccaf15db335dd4347a#comment2578323_1471028).
2. If you are like me that the other kernel option in the grub menu are not booting you can use this [tool](https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh).

For the 2nd option I did the following and this fixed all my app chronium-based (google-chrome, vs code, MongoDb Compass etc...):

1. `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh`
2. `chmod +x ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh`
3. `sudo mv ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh /usr/local/bin/`
4. `uname -r` to view current kernel version that was 5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency
5. `sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -c` that checks for updated version of the kernel linux
6. `sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -r` this list all the possible kernel version available because I wasn't really sure to switch to a major release of the kernel like v6.X.Y
7. I picked the latest 5.19.Z so I submitted this command `sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i v5.19.17`. This download the resources needed and install the kernel over the previous one.
8. `reboot`

After the reboot the system booted up and the kernel was changed to the version defined above. To check it use the previous command `uname -r`.

Now the `code` command launch VS code, `google-chrome` also Chrome and so on, without the `--no-sandbox` option.

The full kernel name now is for my PC:
`Linux eugenio-i9 5.19.17-051917-generic #202210240939 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 24 09:43:01 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`